# Choosing between CSS3 transition-delay and jquery delay();

Tags: jquery, css, delay, css-transitions

Using jQuery, I am incrementally adding the class "go" to the divs

```
    div {
       tranform:translate(20px,20px);
       opacity:0;
       transition:.3s;
    }

    div.go {
      transform:none;
      opacity:1;
    }
```

I want a slight incremental delay for each of the divs as they fly in. There are two methods I could use to achieve this.

1. Set an incremental CSS3 `transition-delay` as an inline style to the divs
2. Use jQuery `delay()` on adding the class `.go` to the divs

Anyone have an idea which is the better method regarding performance? Thanks!

Comment: CSS3 is far better especially for mobile device. CSS3 can take advantage of GPU acceleration.

Comment: CCS will most likely be much better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the JQuery approach would be more more flexible from an App development perspective. Right off the bat it would let you add checks (security, user prefs, browser/platform specific functionality) before showing your DIV. It just depends on your application.

If all you want is a delayed application of a property the CSS solution would be good enough. However I suspect that JQuery/Javascript would be more widely supported across more browsers and platforms (think mobile) than say CSS3 transition-delay. The performance impact would be trivial.

Hope this helps. Good Luck.